# NSArrayM unrecognized selector error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I need some help understanding why I am getting an `unrecognized selector error`

I have a `NSMutableDictionary`

```
@interface CallDetailViewController () {
    NSMutableDictionary * thisDictionary;
}

@end
```

That gets populated from the MasterTabController

```
- (void) some method  {
thisDictionary = [[(MasterTabController *)self.tabBarController detailDictionary] mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"Check dictinoary: %@", [thisDictionary description]);

}
```

Outputting a description shows the data is there

> Check dictinoary: (
>           {
>   DATEIN = "2015-12-11 13:33:41";
>   "ETA" = "2015-12-14 13:54:16";
>   RecordKey = 2961;
>   Destination = "Some address";
>   Location = "Some location";
>   } )

But when I try to access an object in it:

```
NSLog(@"Destination: %@", [thisDictionary objectForKey:@"Destination"]);
```

I get the following error.

> -[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a73f9a0
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a73f9a0'

The array is populated from a JSON value that returns an array of records called Record. After the JSON is returned, I pull out just section that contains the record.

```
NSDictionary * dictTowx = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[dictJSON objectForKey:@"ThisResponse"]];
NSDictionary * dictData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[dictTowx objectForKey:@"Data"]];
NSArray * arrRecordSet  = [dictData objectForKey:@"Recordset"];
NSDictionary * dicRecord= [arrRecordSet objectAtIndex:0];
self.detailDictionary   = [dicRecord objectForKey:@"Record"];
```

The RAW JSON:

```
 {
    ThisResponse =     {
        Data =         {
            Recordset =             (
                                {
                    Record =                     (
                                                {
                            DATEIN = "2015-12-11 13:33:41";
            "ETA" = "2015-12-14 13:54:16";
            RecordKey = 2961;
            Destination = "Some address";
            Location = "Some location";
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        };
    };
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Somehow your `thisDictionary` becomes an NSMutableArray. What is the actual code? Are you sure `-detailDictionary` is returning the correct type?

Comment: Can you show us the source JSON?

Comment: @Tommy added the raw json plus how I'm parsing it

Comment: That's not JSON, that's an NSLog of what was decoded. But, regardless, it means that your JSON specifies an array of dictionaries as the 'Record', not a single dictionary. So that's where the array is coming from. It's in the input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to assign like this

```
self.detailDictionary   = [[dicRecord objectForKey:@"Record"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

and then access like this

```
 NSLog(@"Destination: %@", [thisDictionary objectForKey:@"Destination"]);
```

Enjoy programming.

Comment: That's the answer! He's getting `({` because he's logging an array of dictionaries. Gosh I'm thick some days. (EDIT: unrelated, but `thisDictionary[0][@"Destination"]` would be much more idiomatic nowadays, if you forgive calling something a dictionary that isn't)

Comment: How is my dictionary being converted to an array?

Comment: I added how I populated the dictionary.

Comment: thisDictionary doesn't respond to objectectAtIndex.... as it's a dictionary and not an array.

Comment: @Firemarble See my edited answer. Hope it will work.

Comment: @DharmbirSingh check my parsing code one more time. I made an error in copy-and-pasting

Comment: Thanks so much! I guess I just didn't notice that it WAS an array object that was put in the dictionary.

Comment: @Firemarble Welcome dude.

Answer (score -2):

```
- (void) some method  {
thisDictionary = [[(MasterTabController *)self.tabBarController detailDictionary] mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"Check dictinoary: %@", [thisDictionary description]);

}
```

try replacing

```
thisDictionary = [[(MasterTabController *)self.tabBarController detailDictionary] mutableCopy];
```

with

```
thisDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary: [[{MasterTabController *)self.tabBarController detailDictionary] mutableCopy]]];
```

i think your problem may be you are not instantiating the dictionary before setting it to objects from another.